# IOS Keyboard showing onClick event of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, mobile-safari, youtube-javascript-api

I have been looking in to the focus() on an input field in IOS using javascript. But there is no way you can do it.

Please some senior JS guru help up all in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.focus) to open the keyboard on mobile device, like this :

**HTML** :

```
<button onclick="setFocus('test');">Set Focus</button>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

**Javascript** :

```
 function setFocus(idInput){
     document.getElementById(idInput).focus();
 }
```

---

*Reference*

- [MDN element.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.focus)